# I have a toggle button but need to have it smoothly expand instead of abruptly

Tags: javascript

I have a magnifying glass and when you click on it it expands as a search box but the transition is abrupt. How to make it smoothly toggle. Here's my code:

Navbar w/ text

```
  <!-- Define your search form -->
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <!-- Define a button to toggle the search area -->
    <button id='search-button' class='btn btn-default ' style="background-color: #ffffff !important;"><img src="magnifying-glass-search1.png"></button>
    <!-- Create your entire search form -->
    <div id='search-form' class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id='search-icon' class="input-group-addon"><img src="magnifying-glass-search1.png"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
  // When your page loads
  $(function(){
     // When the toggle areas in your navbar are clicked, toggle them
     $("#search-button, #search-icon").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#search-button, #search-form").toggle();
     });
  })  
  </script>
```

Comment: Read the docs, http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: When I add $("#search-button, #search-form").toggle("slow"); it does the trick but now the search box starts from one line down and slowly moves up vertically. I dont want that. Also I find that when i press on the magnifying glass the height of the nav increases.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an easing function name to the `toggle` function. Like this:

```
$(function(){
     // When the toggle areas in your navbar are clicked, toggle them
     $("#search-button, #search-icon").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#search-button, #search-form").toggle(250, "linear");
     });
  })
```

Also you should be hiding the div that contains your search input so that when you toggle it will show and the icon will hide.

Comment: Even with this the search box is going one line below and starts to rise up. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change animation speed using:

```
$("#search-button, #search-form").toggle(5000);
```

or with key word (additionally you can add action when tha animation is completed):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // When your page loads
  $(function(){
     // When the toggle areas in your navbar are clicked, toggle them
     $("#search-button, #search-icon").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#search-button, #search-form").toggle("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
     });
  })  
  </script>
```

Comment: Even when I add a number for some reason the search box is bumped on the line below and slowly starts going up. Is there  way to correct this?

Comment: ok I managed to fix the height to constant but still the transition is not happening smooth. Any ideas?

Comment: Right now the code is: <script type='text/javascript'>
      // When your page loads
      $(function(){
         // When the toggle areas in your navbar are clicked, toggle them
         $("#search-button, #search-icon").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
          $("#search-button,#search-form").toggle("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
     });
  })  
    </script>